# Updating the embedded document with new property (in the latest array item) in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I habe a mongo docuemnt like below:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ccb655071d4c2ceebe190c"),
        "session_details" : [
                {
                        "session_start" : 1,
                        "session_complete" : 1,
                        "started_at" : ISODate("2017-09-28T08:42:19.770Z"),
                        "event_count" : 2
                },
                {
                        "session_start" : 1,
                        "session_complete" : 1,
                        "started_at" : ISODate("2017-09-28T08:53:08.618Z"),
                        "event_count" : 1
                },
                {
                        "session_start" : 1,
                        "session_complete" : 1,
                        "started_at" : ISODate("2017-09-28T09:19:42.726Z")
                }
        ],
        "session_id" : "12312312313123",
}
```

I am updating the latest session_deatils like below:

```
    session=collection.find_one({"session_id":session_id})
    total_impression = len(session["session_details"])
    latest_session_details = session["session_details"][session_details-1]
    latest_session_started_at = latest_session_details.get("started_at")
```

then I am doing the update like below:

```
collection.update({"session_details.started_at": latest_session_started_at }, {"$set":{"session_details.$.event_count":3}})
```

As from the above you can see I am hitting the DB twice, is it possible to update the docs using single query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the `event_count` field is always missing from where you want to set it you can do this:

```
collection.update({
    "session_id": session_id,
    "session_deatils.event_count": {
        $exists: false
    }
}, {
    "$set": {
        "session_deatils.$.event_count": 3
    }
})
```

If that is not the case then your current solution is a little verbose but ultimately the only way of achieving what you want.

There is some work done around the update of arrays for the next version of MongoDB but that, unfortunately, still doesn't solve your problem: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27089

P.S.: You might want to correct the spelling of `deatils` to `details`.